# How to decrypt and use the encrypted database.yml using secure_yaml in Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, rubygems

I was trying to encrypt the username, password and database name in the database.yml file using secure_yaml in Rails project.

I was able to encrypt using the secret key and save the encrypted database name in database.yml file.

But I am not aware, how should I decrypt the database name and use in my application.

The secure_yaml documentation says "Within your app", but I don't know where to do it.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/secure_yaml/2.0.2

My decrypted db name is something like this : ENC(2Q1tkliN6Ei45tCRg9s=)

But I don't how to decrypt this db name to use in the application.

While running my application I got an error db not found (encrypted db name).

How to decrypt the db name to use in the application.?

Comment: Don't ever commit secrets into your source control, encrypted or not.

Comment: Please tell how to decrypt the db name to use in the application

Comment: What’s wrong with using `SecureYaml::load(File.open('database.yml'))` as specified in the documentation you’ve linked?

Comment: Where should I use that? In which file?

Comment: I believe where you establish a connection to the database.

Comment: I put these 2 lines in application.rb. 

require 'secure_yaml' decrypted_yaml = SecureYaml::load(File.open('config/database.yml'))

But got an error like this:
`retrieve_secret_key': PROPERTIES_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD env property not found (RuntimeError)

Comment: PROPERTIES_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD env property not found.  Why this error occurs?

Comment: Look at point 3) in the secure_yaml docs. You need to set PROPERTIES_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD as an environment variable in the shell you start your application in.